# MvcSiteMapProvider with HTTPS

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider, sitemap.xml

Our application is using MvcSiteMapProvider - 2.0.0.0 version. we would like to have HTTPS version of links listed in sitemap.xml even though it is a HTTP request.

Example: 
If requested url is http://dummywebsitefortesting.com/sitemap.xml then all the `<loc>` tags should contain HTTPS version .i.e. ,  .....etc.

Is above requirement is possible in 2.0.0.0 version ? I tried to add  protocol="https" but there is no luck. I tried to add hostName="www.website1.com" but there is no luck aswell.

Regards,
Kris

Answer (score 1):

The `Protocol` and `HostName` properties were not added until [version 4.6.1](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/releases/tag/v4.6.1).

Prior to that, the only support for HTTPS was to use the `Url` property, which changes the node to make an absolute URL match, rather than using .NET routing (controller, action, etc.).

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" url="https://www.example.com"/>
```

However, I am pretty sure the `Url` property didn't function correctly before version `4.0.0`.

See the related comments [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/119#issuecomment-36240714) and [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/119#issuecomment-36240895) about SSL support during development of 4.x.

Do note that `MvcSiteMapProvider` version 4.x supports .NET framework 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5 as well as MVC 2 - 5. Although [upgrading is not quite seamless](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4), it would probably be worth it to move on from such an old and buggy version of `MvcSiteMapProvider` IMHO, especially since you require functionality that didn't exist in version 2.x that now exists in the latest version.